# Call atoi (Assembler) printf (Assembler)

Tags: assembly

I'm practicing programming in Assembly, making code C.
I don't understand the conversion of a parameter to an integer using atoi.
Can someone explain to me how I as interpret the following code segment:

```
movl    12(%ebp), %eax  ; move a parameter to %eax
addl    $4, %eax        ; add 4 bytes
movl    (%eax), %eax    ; magic things
movl    %eax, (%esp)    ; magic things
call    atoi            ; atoi call
movl    %eax, 24(%esp)  ; asign the result of a magic procedure to a new variable
```

I understand some instructions, but the magic procedures are a little bit ambiguous to me.

Also, I want to know how works the call to the function printf, this is the segment of the code:

```
movl    $.LC1, %eax  ; assing the string (%d\n) to %eax
movl    28(%esp), %edx  ; move the value to print to %edx
movl    %edx, 4(%esp)   ; magic things
movl    %eax, (%esp)    ; magic things
call    printf          ; call to printf
```

Thanks in advance for the support.

Comment: what's magic about them? the paranthesis are like dereferencing a pointer , afaik

Comment: Sorry if the question is too noob, but, is the first time that I read, use, and "translate" Assembly; and I found a lot of texts explain the same thing that you are saying... I need something more explicit. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

%eax is the value stored in the register

(%eax) is value in memory using the value stored in eax

E.g.
`movl 4, %eax`
This sets the value of eax to 4.

The value of (%eax) is now whatever is located in memory at the address of 4.

```
movl    (%eax), %eax    ; move the value in memory of eax  (value eax points to) to the address of register eax
movl    %eax, (%esp)    ; move the address of eax to the value in memory of esp (value that esp points to)

movl    %edx, 4(%esp)   ; move the address of edx to the value in memory of esp + 4 
movl    %eax, (%esp)    ; move the address of eax to the value in memory of esp
```

The reason the first example of yours has just `movl    %eax, (%esp)` is because atoi only takes one argument.

The second example uses `movl %edx, 4(%esp)` because eax is already being used and printf takes two arguments.

Comment: Now, I think this is the same thing than pointers in C...

While mov $4, 4(%esp) is the same that int a=4; 
mov (%eax), %eax is the same that int *eax = %eax

This is correct?

Comment: `movl    (%eax), %eax `   is similar to  `register_eax = *(unsigned long *)register_eax;` in C.

Comment: second line is confusing imho. you refer to the "address of %eax" as the first argument to movl, but how can a register have an address? addresses are for memory. registers aren't memory. also, "the value of memory of %esp" is confusing too. this is where the term address should be used!

Answer (score 0):

The parenthesis are register-indirect addressing (think pointer-dereferencing). `number(register)` means "add the offset `number` before dereferencing".

On how to call other functions, see the [calling conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions) for your system. For x86-32, see [this](http://www.sco.com/developers/devspecs/abi386-4.pdf).